# UIView not covering status bar area

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, statusbar

I am creating a hamburger menu programmatically.

I am trying to make the side menu (grey `UIView`) cover the status bar area when it is slid out and the `UIView` has constraints that are the size of the screen.

I am hiding the status bar alpha when the gesture begins but for some reason, the background of the status bar is still solid white. See example below:

[image: left screen, menu bar hidden - right screen, menu bar visible]

Is it possible to make a UIView cover this area?

Code for the sidebar:

```
let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

var sideBarUIView: UIView! = {
        let sideBarUIView = UIView()
        sideBarUIView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:1.0, blue:0.21, alpha:0.0)
        sideBarUIView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return sideBarUIView
    }()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(sideBarUIView)
}

        sideBarUIView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        sideBarUIView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenHeight).isActive = true
        sideBarUIView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenWidth).isActive = true
```

I am using this line to hide the status bar:

```
self.statusBarWindow?.alpha = 0.0
```

Comment: Fixed the error thanks to @Sh_Khan answer. Changed the centerYconstraint to a bottomConstraint instead: `sideBarUIView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    lazy var sideBarUIView: UIView! = {
        let sideBarUIView = UIView()
        sideBarUIView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        sideBarUIView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return sideBarUIView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(sideBarUIView)

        sideBarUIView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        sideBarUIView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: screenHeight).isActive = true
        sideBarUIView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5).isActive = true
        sideBarUIView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true


    }

}
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately, but it did give me an idea of how to fix it. I have changed `sideBarUIView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true` for `sideBarUIView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true` and that seemed to have fixed it. Thank you so much for the idea!

Comment: Happy coding ;)